# Ansible copy with bash command in path

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible task:

```
- name: Copy files from A to B
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dst: /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/misc/
  with_items:
   - file.one
   - file.two
```

The problem is, that ansible creates a directory called /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/misc/ (literally) and copies the files there instead of substituting the `$(uname -r)` with the command's output.

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, ansible will run it's setup module and discover facts about the target system.

You can [access these facts like any variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts):

```
- name: Copy files from A to B
    copy:
  src: "{{ item }}"
  dst: /usr/lib/modules/{{ ansible_kernel }}/misc/
  with_items:
   - file.one
   - file.two
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to @joppich's answer, if you want to substitute in a value that is *not* available as a fact, you can use [Registered Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables):

```
- name: Determine kernel version
  command: uname -r
  register: r_uname

- name: Copy files from A to B
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dst: /usr/lib/modules/{{ r_uname.stdout_lines[0] }}/misc/
  with_items:
   - file.one
   - file.two
```

Comment: I like this answer too, thanks for that. I had to choose one though. I literally flipped a coin^^